# word macro crashes when 'while' loop is executed

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a VBA macro(Word2010) script to highlight all the text in italics. But when executed in large file say a document with more than 10 pages the Word get crashed.
I have used the below code for this purpose.

```
Sub Italics_Highlight()
'
' test_italics_highlight_ Macro
'
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim myString As Word.Range
    Set myString = ActiveDocument.Content
    With myString.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Font.Italic = True
        While .Execute
            myString.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            myString.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    MsgBox "Thank you!"
End Sub
```

Could you please help to overcome this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*Word get crashed*" is it crashed like a force close without any error message? Or does it show up an error message? If it is a force close then upgrade your office to the latest build, if it still occurs it is a bug and you will need to contact Microsoft Support. Just a note: If you disable screen updating `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` don't forget to enable it in the end or it might be disabled after you procedure finished.

Comment: I can give you two guesses. First it can be that your document has some strange style formatting somewhere, for example that a found part of italics text runs from inside a table to the next paragraph. This should normally not be a problem, but sometimes people tend to mess up their documents with copy/paste, change markings, etc...
The second guess is that your word/computer is a bit slow and tells you that Word is "not responding". 
Try to debug your code by using step by step and/or breakpoints to find out where the problem occurs

Comment: Thank you for the update.
I added Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end that I forgot to add it here.
I mean that MS Word become completely unresponsive. After I run this code I am not able to do anything further. Still I can see the highlighting is done.
The status of the file in task manager changes to 'Not Responding'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stop at each "found" and apply highlighting. You can do it as part of a Find/Replace:

```
Sub testInfiniteLoop()
    Dim myString As word.Range

    Set myString = ActiveDocument.content
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
    With myString.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Font.Italic = True
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Replacement.Highlight = wdTurquoise
      .wrap = wdFindStop 'stop at the end of the document
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error description looks like your code is running forever and doesn't finish.

1. You might want to add a `DoEvents` inside your `While` loop to keep Word responsive while running the code.

   ```
   With myString.Find
       .ClearFormatting
       .Text = ""
       .Font.Italic = True
       While .Execute
           DoEvents 'keeps Word responsive
           myString.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
           myString.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       Wend
   End With
   ```
2. I'm not sure if your code will ever stop. The loop might not stop at the end of the document but start again from beginning, and therefore always find something italic again and again, looping forever.

   So you might need to set the `.Wrap = wdFindStop` to stop at the end of the document.
   See [Find.Wrap Property (Word)](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-wrap-property-word).

   ```
   With myString.Find
       .ClearFormatting
       .Text = ""
       .Font.Italic = True
       .Wrap = wdFindStop 'stop at the end of the document
       While .Execute
           DoEvents 'keeps Word responsive
           myString.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
           myString.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       Wend
   End With
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution @PEH 'DoEvents' perfectly works now.
You are correct the loop is never ending because I could still see it automatically highlights italics once if i change any text into italics.
Here '.Wrap = wdFindStop' seems to be not working.

Comment: @vikashvishnu "*seems to be not working*" is completely meaningless. You need to tell what actually happens. With `.Wrap = wdFindStop` the `Find` function definitely stops at the end of the document I just tested the code. So you must be doing something else wrong. You can easily test this by starting with only 2 or 3 italics in your document. And it will stop with `MsgBox "Thank you!"`.

Comment: I meant to say even after using `.Wrap = wdFindStop` my loop still continues. I have also added `MsgBox "Thank you!"` to check if the loop is ends but it still continues. If the document size is small say 4 pages I am getting the message box if it goes beyond that then I am not getting any message box.

Answer (score 0):

The following code not only highlights but also restores whatever highlight settings were previously in force:

```
Sub Italics_Highlight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long: i = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = ""
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Format = True
  .Font.Italic = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

As you can see, you also don't need:

```
Dim myString As Word.Range
Set myString = ActiveDocument.Content
```